# How to call a function into another function with different parameters?

Tags: jython

Part 1:
Write function def setPixelToBlack(pixel) to change each pixel's colour to black.

Part2:
Write the function def setPictureToBlack(picture) which blacks out the picture. The function has to call setPixelToBlack from part 1.

I have set up my setPixelToBlack(pixel) code but do not know how to use it within the setPictureToBlack(picture) function!

```
def setPixelToBlack(pixel):
  for p in getPixels(pixel):
   value = getRed(p)
   setRed(p, value * 0)
   value = getGreen(p)
   setGreen(p, value * 0)
   value = getBlue(p)
   setBlue(p, value * 0)

def setPictureToBlack(picture):
  for p in getPixels(pixel):
    setPixelToBlack(pixel)

> f = pickAFile()
>>p = makePicture(f)
>>>setPictureToBlack(p)
>>>>explore(p), this should black out the image selected!
```

Comment: Shouldn't you call `setPixelToBlack` w/ the pixels you want, uh, set to Black?  `pixel` isn't defined in `setPictureToBlack`, and neither `p` nor `picture` are used.

Comment: But how exactly would I set my pixels to black in the setPixelToBlack without using getPixels()

Answer (score 0):

`for p in getPixels(pixel):` isn't necessary in `setPixelToBlack`, as you're not looking at multiple pixels.
You also don't need to get the original value of the pixel if you're just setting it to zero.
I assume the `getPixels()` function takes in the picture, so change that and `setPixelToBlack(p)` should get you the desired outcome